# Creating request stub with sinon in mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I'm using `mocha` to test some classes and I need to create a stub of `request` library.

I'm using `sinon`,  and I'm able to create a stub of the `request.get` method but I'm not able to create a stub of the `request` method (the http calls try to connect to a server). As I have read, `request.get` is an alias for `request` but when I stub `request.get` it has no effect over `request` calls.

This code works (using `request.get`):

In tests:

```
request = require 'request'

describe "User test", ->
  user = {}
  before (done) ->
    user = new test.user('Ander', 18)    
    sinon.stub(request, 'get').yields(null, {statusCode: 200}, 'foo')        
    done()
  after (done) ->
    request.get.restore()
    done()
  it "testing server response", ->
    user.getData().should.equal 'ander'
```

In source:

```
request = require 'request'

class User
  contructor(@name, @age): ->
  getData: ->
    mydata = ''
    request.get 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/', (err, response, body) ->        
      if not err and response.statusCode == 200
        mydata = body
      else
        err = throw new Error "Errorea"
    mydata
```

But this doesn't work (tries to connect to the supplied url):

In tests:

```
request = require 'request'

describe "User test", ->
  user = {}
  before (done) ->
    user = new test.user('Ander', 18)    
    sinon.stub(request, 'Request').yields(null, {statusCode: 200}, 'foo')
    #Creating the stub this way, doesn't work neither
    #sinon.stub(request, 'get').yields(null, {statusCode: 200}, 'foo')
    done()
  after (done) ->
    request.Request.restore()
    done()
  it "testing server response", ->
    user.getData().should.equal 'ander'
```

In source:

```
request = require 'request'

class User
  contructor(@name, @age): ->
  getData: ->
    mydata = ''
    request 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/', (err, response, body) ->        
      if not err and response.statusCode == 200
        mydata = body
      else
        err = throw new Error "Errorea"
    mydata
```

Which is the right way to create a stub for `request` call? Which is the method to be stubed?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Although `request` is a great library, it is not a good example of well structured API. And because module `request` is defined as a function with additional methods (similarly like `express`), as what I know you can't create stub for function `request` with `sinon`.

The best thing you can do is to avoid to use `request` function in your code and use only `request.get`, `request.post`, etc., which you can easily stub.

Creating stub for `Request` in your second example doesn't help because Request is not a method, see [source code](https://github.com/mikeal/request).

Comment: or you can use `nock` instead

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is still looking for an answer for this, it looks like you can create a stub for request using sinon:

```
before(function(done){
  sinon
    .stub(request, 'get')
    .yields(null, null, JSON.stringify({login: "bulkan"}));
  done();
});
```

more details can be found [here](http://bulkan-evcimen.com/testing_with_mocha_sinon)

Comment: Bianca - I saw that solution as well but unfortunately that's not what Ander2 is looking for. What you've posted there is how to create a stub of request.get which is what Ander2 posted he was already able to do. The issue is not being able to mock 'Request' which can be called without specifying the http method - request(options, callback); I have the same problem. Shame the solution seems to be to avoid using Request and specifically go with request.get, though its not a big change i guess

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround would be generating a stub using **sinon** module and the **request** dependency in the corresponding module can be overridden using **proxyquire**.

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('something', function(){
  var request;
  var overriddenModule;
  before(function(){
    request = sinon.stub();
    // overriding the 'request' dependency with the stub
    overriddenModule = proxyquire('path_to_module_using_request', {'request': request});     
  });
  it("should do something",function(done){
    // stubbing the request(options,callback) method
    request.withArgs(sinon.match.any,sinon.match.any).yields(null,null,responseBody);
    overriddenModule.method_which_is_doing_request;
    // our logic and assertions before calling done()
  });  
});
```

For more info, check [this article on Unit Testing with Mocks in Node](http://vansande.org/2015/03/22/unit_testing_with_mocks_in_node_js/)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in one of the answers to the question [How to mock request and response in nodejs to test middleware/controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487809/how-to-mock-request-and-response-in-nodejs-to-test-middleware-controllers), the **node-mocks-http** package provides a way to build request and response mocks.