# Use sinon stub for request constructor

Tags: node.js, sinon

I have implement node js code to call HTTP API's using request module.
For get, post, put, delete, I have directly called request() of require module,

```
var sendRequest = function(req, callback) {
    request(req, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err, null, res);
        } else {
            callback(null, res);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to invoke sendRequest() but mock the response of request().
Any pointers for this.

Comment: You can use sinon like described here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050507/creating-request-stub-with-sinon-in-mocha/32868852#32868852

Comment: I went through the link, but in that case we will have to write independent get(), put(), etc. As you can check above I have implemented on request() which takes care of all the method types. I need to mock that particulare request().

Comment: @PriyankaWare did you find the answer?

Answer (score 2):

One way to get it stubbed without anything but sinon, is to stub the inner class of Request, which conveniently offers its prototype, like this

```
stub = sinon.stub(request.Request.prototype, "init");
stub.callsFake( options => options.callback(null, {statusCode: 200}, "faked response"));
```

Where `options` in the `callsFake` are processed by the `request` function and the passed into the `Request.prototype.init`.

Now your callback parameters, are the ones expected in your `var sendRequest = function(req, callback) {...}` function

Answer (score 0):

One of the many options is to use [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to stub the request module:

```
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire')
  , assert = require('assert')
  , requestStub = function (req, callback) { callback(req); };

// assuming you export the sendRequest from that file
var sendRequest = proxyquire('./sendRequest', { 'request': pathStub });

describe('sendRequest', function() {
    it('request', function (done) {
        var someReq = {a: 'b'};
        sendRequest(someReq, function (req) {
            assert.equal(someReq, req);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, but what I observed is to make it working I will have to export sendRequest(). In my case, sendRequest is prototype method and I cannot export it.

Comment: @PriyankaWare you're always welcome. How much harm will it cause if you export the function? Can you move it to a separate private file maybe?

Comment: It will not cause any harm for sure. But that is the methodology we are following to define all methods as prototype methods. If it is the only option I can go for that change, else it will be great if we get some alternative for that.

Comment: @PriyankaWare by "prototype method" you mean a method attached to a JS class-like function?

Comment: Yes exactly. In my JS file I am creating DataSource and attaching few prototype methods to it and in my test file I am creating new Data Source requiring that JS file and the invoking the prototype methods.

Comment: @PriyankaWare why don't you just proxyquire the request module itself?