# Node Js TDD - Mock Object for winston logger and request headers

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, chai

I am writing unit test cases for one of my node modules using `mocha`, `chai`, `should` and `expect`. Where some function signatures are like this -

```
module.exports.user = (logger, options) => {
 let db = options.db,
 smtp = options.smtp

 logger.info('The user name is '+smtp.username)
}
```

My question is how do I mock the `options` and `logger` parameter, since the options come from `req.headers.options` and logger comes from `req.headers.options.logger` I am putting the options and logger using a middleware in server file.

Answer (score 1):

Use [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) to mock the object req.headers.options

You can start with [this similary question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050507/creating-request-stub-with-sinon-in-mocha)